# Django REST framework api root empty

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've setup a Django REST framework project but the api root hasn't been populated with anything eg a users ViewSet and I can't access the expected url with a list of users.

There is one app users, with a custom user model. (and the django project is named api)

main urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('users.urls')),
]
```

the users app urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from users.views import CustomUserViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("users", CustomUserViewSet, 'users')

urlpatterns = [
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

users models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

users serialisers.py

```py
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

users app views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet
from .serializers import CustomUserSerializer
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserViewSet(ViewSet):
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all(
```

And empty api root at `localhost:8000/api/`
[image]

and 404 error at `localhost:8000/api/users/`
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using just `Viewset`, you need to implement the actions.

From the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset):

> The ViewSet class does not provide any implementations of actions. In
> order to use a ViewSet class you'll override the class and define the
> action implementations explicitly

You can add a `list` action like in the [example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example):

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
class CustomUserViewSet(ViewSet):
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Or (maybe what you are looking for) using something like [ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) that already includes implementations for various actions:

```
class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks what a silly error it was ModelViewSet I meant to put in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have to simply replace

`class CustomUserViewSet(ViewSet):`

with

`class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):`